# Make an array of classes

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I need to create an array of another class.
Example:

```
namespace std
{
      public class Car
      {
           double number,id;

           public Car()
           {
               // initializing my variables for example:
               number = Random.nextdouble();
           }

      }
      public class Factory
      {
           public Factory(int num)
           {
               Car[] arr = new Car(num);
           }
      }
}
```

The problem is I get this error:

> 'Car' does not contain a constructor that takes '1' arguments

I just need to have an array of `Car` in `Factory` class (the car variables are initialized with its constructor).

Comment: What are you trying to do with `new car(num)`? what is `num` supposed to do?  Your constructor for car takes no parameters

Comment: @AdamPlocher: Yes, but look at the question title and the variable he's trying to assign it to - it's pretty clear he's trying to create an array.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that shortly after commenting :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've just used the wrong brackets. You always use square brackets for arrays and indexers. Round brackets are to invoke methods, constructors etc. You meant:

```
car[] arr = new car[num];
```

Note that conventionally .NET types are Pascal-cased, so your types should be `Car` and `Factory` rather than `car` and `factory`.

Also note that after creating the array, each element will be a null reference - so you *shouldn't* write:

```
// Bad code - will go bang!
Car[] cars = new Car[10];
cars[0].SomeMethod(0);
```

Instead:

```
// This will work:
Car[] cars = new Car[10];
cars[0] = new Car(); // Populate the first element with a reference to a Car object
cars[0].SomeMethod();
```

Comment: thanks,problem solved.
but another question: can i declare the arr outside the constructor without the num value? in other words make a array dynamic in size?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `[]` not `()` when you declaring an array or indexers.

```
car[] arr = new car[num];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Car
    {
        public double number { get; set; }
        public Car()
        {
            Random r = new Random();            
            number = r.NextDouble();// NextDouble isn't static and requires an instance
        }
    }
    public class Factory
    {
        //declare Car[] outside of the constructor
        public Car[] arr;
        public Factory(int num)
        {
            arr = new Car[num]; 
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Factory f = new Factory(3);
            f.arr[0] = new Car();
            f.arr[1] = new Car();
            f.arr[2] = new Car();
            foreach (Car c in f.arr)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c.number);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @JonSkeet - In the author's own example he ignores both `iD` and the `num` since the parameter isn't actually used.

Comment: @Ramhound: But he's clearly *trying* to use `num` in the factory constructor in the question, and previously this answer ignored it.

Comment: @kashif: Yes, it's better. It's not really clear why you've introduced the local variables (and it will go bang if `num` is 0, 1 or 2) but I'm fine with it.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Only after the fifth time did I read the author's code did I realize what he was trying to do with `num`.

Comment: num is the actual array size (number of objects from car class)

Answer (score 0):

If your requirements doesn't constrain to use only Array, you can use a typed list.

```
List<Car> = new List<Car>(num); 
//num has to be the size of list, but a list size is dinamically increased.
```

The error in your code is that array should be initialized as follows:

```
public class factory
      {
           public factory(int num)
           {
           car[] arr = new car[num];
           }
      }
```

Regards,